# Pull date in date wise by passing date manually

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

How to Pull data wise count from table by passing date manually,

My Code:

```
select count(*),id,time_stamp 
from tab 
where trunc(time_stamp)='12-11-2018'
group by id,time_stamp.
```

Is getting an error like `not a valid month`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must convert varchar to date, using [to_date](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) function

```
 select count(*),id,time_stamp 
 from tab 
 where trunc(time_stamp)=to_date('12-11-2018','dd-mm-yyyy') 
 group by id,time_stamp.
```

> TO_DATE converts char of CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, or NVARCHAR2 datatype to a value of DATE datatype.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply use a date string of any format while comparing with dates, it has to either match the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` or you must convert it using `TO_DATE`.

Moreover, prefer not to use `TRUNC` on a date column directly in `where clause` for comparison. It will be slower and may not utilise an index if it exists on the column `time_stamp` (unless you have a function based index on `TRUNC(time_stamp)`.  Use simple `DATE/TIMESTAMP` literals with `>=` & `<` conditions.

```
 select count(*),id,time_stamp 
 from tab 
 where time_stamp >= DATE '2018-11-12' AND time_stamp < DATE '2018-11-12' + 1
 group by id,time_stamp
```